# Covariance function of a differencing in time series $z_t = x_t-x_{t-1}$

Tags: statistics, covariance, time-series

I am having trouble finding the covariance function for a differencing of a stationary time series $x_t$.

Letting $z_t = x_t-x_{t-1}$

I see that $E[z_t]=0$ so

$$\gamma_z(h)=E[z_{t+h}z_t]$$
is what I want to simplify.

I understand that

$$\begin{align}
\gamma_x(h) & = E[(x_{t+h}-\mu_x)(x_t-\mu_x)]\\
& = E[x_{t+h}x_t]-\mu_x^2\\
\end{align}$$

or in other words

$$E[x_{t+h}x_t]=\gamma_x(h)+\mu_x^2$$

so I am thinking that this should be incorporated in the expression, but all I get is

$$\gamma_z(h) = \gamma_x(h)+\mu_x^2-E[x_{t+h}x_{t-1}]-E[x_{t+h-1}x_t]+E[x_{t-1+h}x_{t-1}]$$

I am just starting to learn time series so it would be very helpful if there is some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: So you want to find an expression for $\text{cov}(z_{t+h},z_{t})$? If so, you have \begin{align}
\text{cov}(z_{t+h},z_{t}) &= \mathbb{E}[z_{t+h}z_{t}] - \mathbb{E}[z_{t+h}]\mathbb{E}[z_{t}] \quad \text{(by definition)} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[z_{t+h}z_{t}] \quad \text{(as you have $\mathbb{E}[z_{t}] = 0$, though I'm not sure why this is the case)}\\
&= \mathbb{E}[(x_{t+h}-x_{t+h-1})(x_{t}-x_{t-1})] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x_{t+h}x_{t}] - \mathbb{E}[x_{t+h}x_{t-1}] - \mathbb{E}[x_{t+h-1}x_{t}] + \mathbb{E}[x_{t+h-1}x_{t-1}] \quad \text{(by linearity of the expectation)}
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm, we get the same expression.  $E[z_t]=0$ because if $x_t$ is stationary one of its condition is that $E[x_t]=\mu$.  Just that the first term can be expressed as $\gamma_x(h)+\mu^2$.  

Thank you !  At least I know that my algebra is right.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the part of your question that said $x$ was stationary. No worries, glad I could help.